# complex get_posts() query to select child pages

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, get-posts, child-pages

I have pages on 2 levels under the main deparments page like below.

```
Departments
--Department 1 
-----Course 1 
-----Course 2 
--Department 1 
-----Course 3 
-----Course 4 
--Department 3 
--Department 4
```

On the Departments page I want to list all course pages, not department pages Except for Department 3 and 4 because they dont have and course pages below them.

How do I achieve this exactly? This is what I have so far...

```
$childpages = get_posts( 

array(

'post_type' => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'child_of'    => $post->post_parent,
//'post__in' => array(354, 351),    //NOT WORKING   
'post_parent__not_in' => array($post->ID),      
'post_status' => 'publish',
)
);

return $childpages;
```

This returns all course pages but not the Department 3 and 4 pages.  I tried to use **post__in** with those post IDs but this returned nothing.

Comment: How are departments and courses related? What type are they? (custom) taxonomy/post type?

Comment: they are both just pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop for this to handle the condition:

```php
/** list for course and childless department pages */
$course_and_childless_department_pages = array();

/** get department pages */
$department_pages = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
) );

foreach ( $department_pages as $department_page ) {

    /** get course pages (for department page) */
    $course_pages_for_department_page = get_children( array(
        'post_parent' => $department_page->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );

    if ( empty( $course_pages_for_department_page ) ) {
        /** add empty department page to list */
        $course_and_childless_department_pages[] = $department_page;
    } else {
        /** add course pages to list */
        $course_and_childless_department_pages = array_merge( $course_and_childless_department_pages, $course_pages_for_department_page );
    }
}

return $course_and_childless_department_pages;
```

You wrote that you are on the Departments page, so the value of `$post` is the Departments page.

`$course_and_childless_department_pages` array will contain all the pages in [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) format.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!